# r geom_smooth can't fit a linear regression with no intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fit a linear regression line without an intercept using geom_smooth(). I tried "formula = y~x", "formula = y~x+0", "formula = y~x-1", they all gave me intercepts... what is wrong? please help

```
library("tidyverse")
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x+0)+
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 300)+
  stat_cor(label.y = 250) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `stat_regline_equation` will not inherit the formula from `geom_smooth`, you have to explicitly tell `stat_regline_equation` as well that you want a model without intercept:

Note: As a reference I added a `geom_smooth` for a model with intercept, which shows that `geom_smooth` already does as you told.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, color= "black", se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + 0) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 300, formula = y ~ x + 0) +
  stat_cor(label.y = 250) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]