# How to force set the y intercept to start from the origin using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[The plot shows that there is a non-0 Y intercept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGqSz.png)

The code for this is as follows:

```
calibration_plot_455 <- ggplot(df_455,
                           aes(x = concentrations, y = abs_slopes_455)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, alpha = 1, color = "#045a8d") +
  stat_smooth(geom = "line", method = "lm", alpha = 0.7, se = FALSE, 
              formula = y~x-1, color = "#2b8cbe")+
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 5, label.x = 0.2, 
                        aes(label = ..eq.label..)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 4.5, label.x = 0.2,
                        aes(label = ..rr.label..)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks = seq(0, 6, by = 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,4.1), expand = FALSE)+
  labs(subtitle = "Calibration at 455 nm ", 
       y = "Absorbance (a.u)",
       x = expression(Concentration~of~Ni^"2+" ~ (mM)))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f1eef6"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(family = "serif", face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(family = "serif", face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

I have used `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` to try and set the y intercept to 0. It looks like it has worked since I see the line starting from the origin, but the equation of the line looks like it does not (since the y intercept is still 0.176).

Is there any way of making it start from the origin and the equation displaying the same?

When I tried this in MS Excel wherein, I could set the intercept 0, the equation of the line comes out to be y = 1.503x (there is no y intercept). I'm sure that this equation is right. I would like to know how to modify the code to reflect the same.

Comment: You have to specify a formula with no intercept in `stat_regline_equation` too, i.e. `stat_regline_equation(..., formula = y ~ x - 1)`. See [r geom_smooth can't fit a linear regression with no intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77624689/r-geom-smooth-cant-fit-a-linear-regression-with-no-intercept/77624846#77624846).